# can't use git, maven and npm behind proxy

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, npm, proxy

I'm currently working behind a proxy and been stuck with it config denying every communication for git or intellij or npm CLIs, I did this:

On git cli:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://xxxxxx
    sslverify = false
[https]
    proxy = http://xxxxxx
    sslVerify = false
```

on intellij I setup the same config to make it work behind my proxy config to be able to download maven dependencies

same as npm config I did

```
   https-proxy = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   proxy = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx"
   strict-ssl = false
```

All this solutions didn't work, All requests keep getting timed out

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the proxy by accessing the following menu:

File> Settings> Appearance & Beahavior> System Settings> HTTP Proxy

[HTTP Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRTeH.png)

Comment: As I said configured the intellij also with same proxy address